Python circular import fix does not work - what is the solution?
I faced the dreaded circular import issue when doing some simple research. I tried the "import " solution but doesn't seem to work. What is the solution to make it work?
Example code (all 3 files are located in the same directory, no other files present in there):
my_subject.py:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from random import randrange
import my_observer


class Subject(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def attach(self, observer: my_observer.Observer) -> None:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def detach(self, observer: my_observer.Observer) -> None:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def notify(self) -> None:
        pass


class ConcreteSubject(Subject):
    _state: int = None
    _observers: list[my_observer.Observer] = []

    def attach(self, observer: my_observer.Observer) -> None:
        print("Subject: Attached an observer.")
        self._observers.append(observer)

    def detach(self, observer: my_observer.Observer) -> None:
        self._observers.remove(observer)

    def notify(self) -> None:
        print("Subject: Notifying observers...")
        for observer in self._observers:
            observer.update(self)

    def some_business_logic(self) -> None:
        print("\nSubject: I'm doing something important.")
        self._state = randrange(0, 10)

        print(f"Subject: My state has just changed to: {self._state}")
        self.notify()


my_observer.py:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import my_subject


class Observer(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def update(self, subject: my_subject.Subject) -> None:
        pass


class ConcreteObserverA(Observer):
    def update(self, subject: my_subject.Subject) -> None:
        if subject._state < 3:
            print("ConcreteObserverA: Reacted to the event")


class ConcreteObserverB(Observer):
    def update(self, subject: my_subject.Subject) -> None:
        if subject._state == 0 or subject._state >= 2:
            print("ConcreteObserverB: Reacted to the event")


observer_main.py:
import my_subject 
import my_observer 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # The client code.

    subject = my_subject.ConcreteSubject()

    observer_a = my_observer.ConcreteObserverA()
    subject.attach(observer_a)

    observer_b = my_observer.ConcreteObserverB()
    subject.attach(observer_b)

    subject.some_business_logic()
    subject.some_business_logic()

    subject.detach(observer_a)

    subject.some_business_logic()

terminal output when running observer_main.py:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samprass/dev/python/practising/design_patterns/observer/observer_main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import my_subject 
  File "/home/samprass/dev/python/practising/design_patterns/observer/my_subject.py", line 3, in <module>
    import my_observer
  File "/home/samprass/dev/python/practising/design_patterns/observer/my_observer.py", line 18, in <module>
    class Observer(ABC):
  File "/home/samprass/dev/python/practising/design_patterns/observer/my_observer.py", line 20, in Observer
    def update(self, subject: my_subject.Subject) -> None:
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'my_subject' has no attribute 'Subject' (most likely due to a circular import)

I tried to use simple "import " instead of "from  import "

Do the answers to this question help at all?

I tried to use simple "import " instead of "from import " That is not a fix at all.  The real fix is to rewrite your code or reorganize your modules.

It looks like you are only using the mutual dependencies for type checking. If so, have a look at typing.TYPE_CHECKING.
